# C#, Adding custom profiles with settings to application

Tags: c#, class, struct

I am trying to create a method that would allow the user to add their own settings profile, by entering their IP,Port,Name basically just a few strings. I would want to use the created profiles all over my project (and later to store it in a json as a local file but thats a another story), what would be the best way to achieve this to be efficient and functional? using a class? struct?  I didnt have any luck with them so far

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think a class will fit best for this. Search in the way of the providers (for users) in .Net. Maybe extend or create your own one. You can store the profiles in your config, or database and access them once, global static within the application.

With the provider pattern you realize a great decoupling of the storage. So if you want to change the storage of the provided profiles in a later stage, you can implement another provider.

Comment: do you mean membership providers? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

Comment: Yep. Depending on your type of application (web/client), you could use that. And extend, or make a custom provider. In that way you can have complete user profiles anywhere, independent from the kind of data storage.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've gone about doing this in the past is writing a config file using XML and saving each setting as an "Application" setting.

After that it's just up to setting up user controls on a Windows Form to be able to save those settings. The great thing out about User Controls is that they are re-useable pieces for each windows form project and you can create a new settings page quickly.

I have a settings project which holds a main form where I add in all of my user controls and just control what the user sees based on a tree view with a handful of nodes to choose from.

I have a function for reading the settings and writing the settings to and from the .config file as well, but in other instances I am reading and writing directory from the app.config.

I've done a few projects in this manner and it works well for my purposes.

Comment: the problem is that my application will need to use multiple setting profiles the same time, and I need to be able to browse trough them fast.

Comment: Browsing through the XML is pretty quick in my experience 

Mine is setup like

    <settings name = "mySetting" serializeAs="String">
        <value>settingValue</value>
    </setting>

There is probably a way to do it with only XML, but it depends on your needs.